# How can I find which processor each thread is running on?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a multi-threaded program, and have been asked to add in an option to put every thread on its very own core (CPU, processor, whatever).

I've written code to do this using [SetThreadAffinityMask()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I get the process' default affinity mask, verify that there are enough processors to do it, then set each thread's affinity mask to include only one of the available processors (and different for each thread).

All this seems to compile and run with no problem, but how do I check if it is actually working?

It seems like there should be some monitoring tool that shows what CPU a thread is running on, but I can't find it. `ProcessExplorer` will show a thread's CPU utilization, but not which CPU that occurred on. I looked through the possible counters that can be used on `perfmon`, but again I could only find % utilization, not which CPU.

It's been suggested I do a GetThreadAffinityMask() and report that, but it seems to me that will just report that I called SetThreadAffinityMask() correctly.

So am I just supposed to take it on faith that SetThreadAffinity() will be doing exactly what I want?

(NOTE: I found quite a few seemingly similar questions on SO, but none that actually contain an answer for this particular question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GetCurrentProcessorNumber()` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683181(v=vs.85).aspx )

Comment: Possibly you will need to do sampling with this function, to make sure the processor number is maintained during the entire execution.

Comment: Hmmm. This would require modifying each thread to monitor this themselves. I suppose I could write some temp debug code to do that. Not optimal, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: ...note that I'm compiling with XP-level libraries, but this link took care of that little issue. https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Jeremy.Jones/GetCurrentProcessorNumberXP.htm

Comment: This ended up working for me, so I'm accepting it. Note that the routine I provided in the comment above does not seem to provide CPU ID numbers based on any discernable scheme. To map them to CPU affinity numbers, I had to manually loop through all affinity bits in a thread and call the routine.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [GetCurrentProcessorNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the processor number of the currently executing thread.